# Replace data in js file

Tags: javascript, json

I have js file called data.js that has one part formatted as json and contain feature data that start and end on certain lines and this creates sphere on the map (there are 5 spheres in total).

So simply I want to use live data to replace data in js from certain to certain line.
For example my sphere 1 data start from 66 and end on line 88, sphere 2 data starts from line 89 and end in line 111 and so on.
How can I replace data in js based on start and end line?
Or option is to delete lines and insert new ones.

Here is example how it looks for one sphere.

```
              {
                "geom": {
                  "pts": [
                    [
                      -291.7346136515533,
                      -487.39223350681385,
                      -3644.701305711841
                    ]
                  ],
                  "r": 38.4956041772686
                },
                "mtl": 0,
                "prop": [
                  "2021-06-01",
                  "21:43",
                  "41,8665",
                  "11,0161",
                  "-16",
                  "SL",
                  "2,4"
                ],
                "lh": 0.0
              },
```

Comment: so let me get this straight.. u have a whole javascript file and you have *some* json in it.. now you want to edit the entire file?? why can't you have that JSON as a separate file.. `require('data.json')` ???

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to mention quite a lot of details. Is this your file? (if so, rewrite the code). Is this client side or server side? (because one has massive restrictions on file manipulation, and the other doesn't). What is the actual file's code you're talking about? (line numbers with files mean nothing, and _don't_ paste or link the entire file: show the reduced version). etc. Remember: you're asking people for help who have no idea what you're working with: explain it to them with that in mind.